# Can I pick 5 numbers that add to 1 billion with equal probability without using simulation?

Tags: python, performance, random, statistics

You have 5 choices, and you want to pick from the five choices randomly.
Instead of simulating that choice 1 billion times, how would you go about getting numbers for each one directly?

This is the simulation:

```
choices = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for i in range (int(1e9)):
    choices[random.randint(0, 4)] += 1
```

But this is quite slow and I don't know how I would get a faster solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If each choice has equal probability then each value should be 1e9/5 == 200,000,000. Is this question about programming or math/stats?

Comment: I want to generate random numbers that follow a normal distribution, but I want each set of generated numbers to be different every time I run the program.

Comment: Still not clear. Your code shows numbers being chosen from a uniform, not a normal, distribution.

Comment: @Woodford For each of the five slots the result follows a normal distribution (because it is a sum of independent draws with same probability) but somehow connected. Unfortunately I lack some math knowledge to solve the actual question.

Comment: If you're testing the randomness of random.randint, then I think you're doing it correctly. There's no quick way to get the result from a billio random.randints without doing this. You can could use another language and/or parallelise it to make it faster. e.g. run 8 instances of 125,000,000 then add the results together,

Comment: What is being done with `choices` after running your billion trials? You’ve provided a code fragment, but no context for it.

Comment: A lot of times, when we say "randomly" in everyday parlance, we mean "uniformly at random", which implies that there is an equal chance of each possible outcome.  In your situation, you probably don't mean, for example, that every number from 1 to 1B has an equal chance of appearing in the output set, because very large numbers leave few possibilities for the other values to have the sum add to 1B.  So, what do you mean by "random"?

Comment: @Him Did you read their code?

Comment: @KellyBundy well, the question title suggests that the individual numbers in the partition of 1B should be equally probable, elsewhere they state "normal distribution", their code suggests a multinomial distribution.  It seems to me that the person most likely to know which of these they want is the OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you could use distribution which by construction add sampled integer numbers to the fixed sum. Simplest is [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution)

Python code (untested)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.multinomial(1000000000, [1/5.]*5, size=1)
np.sum(a)
```

another one could be [Dirichlet-multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet-multinomial_distribution)

Comment: Why untested?..

Comment: @KellyBundy didn't run it, just copied and edited.

Comment: But why? Only takes a few seconds...

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly statisticly balanced, but will always give 5 numbers that add up to 1 billion :

```
# PSEUDO CODE
total = 1e9;
result = [0,0,0,0,0];

foreach i in result :
   result[i] = RANDOM(0,total);
   total -= result[i]
```

EDIT : The last number needs to be the remaining of total instead of a random for this to work

```
# PSEUDO CODE
total = 1e9;
result = [0,0,0,0];

foreach i in result :
   result[i] = RANDOM(0,total);
   total -= result[i]

result.push(total)
```

Comment: so how they would up to 1e9?